# Amazon S3 Cognito - Upload image from image picker - Swift 3

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I have done static image upload to AWS server successfully. When i combine it with imagepicker, I am facing a wierd issue due to which same image is being uploaded to AWS even though I pick and name them differently. The code is as follows:

```
internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
 {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    var imageUrl          = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL
    let imageName         = imageUrl?.lastPathComponent
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
    let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)

    print("image name : \(imageName)")

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: localPath!.path) {
        do {
            try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)?.write(to: localPath!)
            print("file saved")
            //let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: localPath!)
            //let finalURL = localPath!

            //this is in swift 2; above 2 lines are its equivalent in swift3. I think the problem lies here
            //let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: localPath)!
            //imageURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath)

        }catch {
            print("error saving file")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("file already exists")
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: "identity pool id")
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .APSoutheast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    //these are the static values I used that worked perfectly fine with separate images
    //let localFileName = "Alerts_bg"
    //let ext = "png"
    //let remoteName = localFileName + "." + ext
    //let imageURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: localFileName, withExtension: ext)!

    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()

    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!
    uploadRequest.bucket = "bucket"
    let imageAWSName = "ios_" + NSUUID().uuidString + ".jpg"
    uploadRequest.key = imageAWSName
    uploadRequest.body = localPath! as URL
    uploadRequest.contentType = "image/jpg"

    print("req123 : \(uploadRequest)")

    uploadRequest.uploadProgress = { (bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            //self.amountUploaded = totalBytesSent // To show the updating data status in label.
            //self.fileSize = totalBytesExpectedToSend
            print("progress : \(totalBytesSent)/\(totalBytesExpectedToSend)")
        })
    }

    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Upload failed with error: (\(error.localizedDescription))")
        }
        if task.result != nil {

            let s3URL = URL(string: "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/\(imageAWSName)")!
            print("Uploaded to:\(s3URL)")
        }
        return nil
    })

 dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil) //5
 }
```

I have seen lot of blogs such as [this](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/select-image-with-uiimagepickercontroller-and-upload-to-aws-s3-bucket/) and [this](http://jzorz.com/aws-s3-swift-upload-image-from-camera-or-photolibrary/) but these are in earlier versions of swift and I am unable to convert it in Swift 3 and combine imagepicker with AWS properly.
Someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem:

```
let imageAWSName = "ios_" + NSUUID().uuidString + ".jpg"

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
    let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
    let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageAWSName)

    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: localPath!.path) {
        do {
            try UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)?.write(to: localPath!)
            print("file saved")
        }catch {
            print("error saving file")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("file already exists")
    }

    let credentialProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: “your identity pool id”)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .APSoutheast1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()

    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!
    let yourBucketName = “your bucket name”
    uploadRequest.bucket = yourBucketName

    uploadRequest.key = imageAWSName
    uploadRequest.body = localPath! as URL
    uploadRequest.contentType = "image/jpg"

    uploadRequest.uploadProgress = { (bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            //self.amountUploaded = totalBytesSent // To show the updating data status in label.
            //self.fileSize = totalBytesExpectedToSend
            print("progress : \(totalBytesSent)/\(totalBytesExpectedToSend)")
        })
    }

    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Upload failed with error: (\(error.localizedDescription))")
        }
        if task.result != nil {

            let s3URL = URL(string: "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/\(yourBucketName)/\(imageAWSName)")!
            print("Uploaded to:\(s3URL)")
        }
        return nil
    })

    self.picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Make sure the imageAWSName used in localPath is always different as I have done. That is the main thing otherwise AWS will save same image multiple times even though you pick different images from picker.

Hope it helps someone in future!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you are doing this:

```
let photoURL          = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
let localPath         = photoURL.appendingPathComponent(imageName!)
```

you are creating localPath as `URL`.
So when you are doing:

```
let imageURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath)
```

It's giving error, because localPath is `URL` not `String`.
Here you can directly using as:

```
let imageURL = localPath!
```

Comment: So you mean to say i can use localPath directly? I don't need to form the URL again right?

Comment: Yes, that will solve your 'cannot convert value...' error

Comment: Ok. I removed both those lines. Still facing issue in combining static AWS code with image picker. Can you help me with that?

Comment: This is about solving `URL` to `String` issue, any other issue regarding AWS then please edit question with exact issue.

Comment: I am unable to combine the image picker and aws code. That is the main issue